# Why is java's Object toString method defined as it is?

Tags: java

In the [Java API specification for the Object class for the toString method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()), there is the line "It is recommended that all subclasses override this method."

While I don't have a better idea for what this method should do in the Object class, I would like to know if there is any particular reason it is defined the way it is (i.e. as

```
getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```

).

Comment: The hash code, among other things, will tell you with a reasonable degree of certainty whether one object is value-equal to another.  In this context, it (more or less) guarantees that the string you get back from two unequal objects will be *unique.*  Without knowing anything else about an object, this is really all you can meaningfully do with `toString()`, which is why overriding is recommended.